# Entity Framework 6 memory leak

Tags: c#, entity-framework, memory-leaks

I use EF6 with an SQLite database. I create and dispose `DBContext` objects for each request, but want to I cache the `SQLiteConnection` objects, so the database stays cached in memory. It looks as if EF leaks memory under these circumstances.

Here's a minimal working sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // use one connection for the lifetime of the application
        using (var conn = new System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:MEMORY:"))
        {
            // create sample DB
            conn.Open();
            using (var context = new MyContext(conn, false))
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE SomeTable(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)");

            while (true)
            {
                // access database 
                using (var context = new MyContext(conn, false))
                {
                    var x = System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(context.SomeTable);
                }
                // show memory usage
                System.Console.Write("{0:0,0} Bytes   \r", System.GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public MyContext(System.Data.Common.DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    { }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SomeTableRow> SomeTable { get; set; }
}

[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("SomeTable")]
class SomeTableRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

If I run this, the process memory usage keeps increasing.

I think the problem is that `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection` subscribes to the `StateChange` event on the connection object and never unsubscribes from it.

My (very ugly) workaround is to manually "clear" the `StateChange` event field after each use, like this:

```
conn
    .GetType()
    .GetField("StateChange", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
    .SetValue(conn, null);
```

Is this a known problem? Is there a better workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Calling Dispose() on the EntityConnection seems to resolve the issue.

```
public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
{
    private EntityConnection _entityConnection;

    public CustomDbContext(EntityConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    {
        _entityConnection = connection;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (disposing && _entityConnection != null)
            _entityConnection.Dispose();
    }
}
```